# Do I need memcached with Opcache ?

Tags: php, wordpress, memcached, opcache, php-5.5

I don't know anything about caching other than having read that people use APC/Opcache/Memcache/Memchached/Varnish ... to makes PHP go faster :)

So, I tried APC last week since I was on PHP5.4, but then updated my to PHP5.5 so I could use Opcache. So, now that Opcache is working, I need to even make my wordpress site faster, and since I have heard that APC is not compatible with opcache, I would like to know if memcached is OK to use, as I am almost certain varnish is OK because it is not related to PHP.

So, will using memcached further improve my site?

Comment: Consider using memcached for PHP session storage.

Comment: @J.D.Pace Only for sessions? How? do you have a link ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php -- you can do it automatically with the PHP.ini.  Memcached is useful for many other things, but PHP Sessions would be a quick win if they're currently stored in files.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

OPcache is for accelerating code access. memcached is for accelerating data access. They are completely different, and completely independent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its good to know they are different and can work together improve speed

Comment: However, you could use opcache for data access by writing data into php files.

Answer (score 7):

While OpCache doesn't support the user-side caching functionality of APC, it can still be a useful tool, and so the Pecl module, [APCU](http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu) was extracted from the original. It's entirely compatible with the original, but leaves the zend-code cache for OpCache.